# How can i show Deadbeaf music-player queue

Tags: music, music-player, deadbeef

How can i show Deadbeaf music-player queue,
deadbeafmusicplayer has the option to queue music files, 
but thtere seems no way to have this listed, like a playlist tab or so

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a clear "option to queue music files" in deadbeef; but I guess this would mean adding files to a playlist - which the following solution does:

There are some [DeaDBeeF plugins](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/plugins.html).

Install the DeaDBeeF File Browser plugin (from here: [i686](http://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/files/plugins/ddb_misc_filebrowser_GTK2-i686-0.4.zip/download), [x86_64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/files/plugins/ddb_stereo_widener-x86_64-0.1.zip/download))

(On their site they say to put the .so file in: ~/.local/lib/deadbeef/

For installation from PPA it is also /usr/lib/deadbeef

while for the installation from .deb: /opt/deadbeef/lib/deadbeef)

Go to Preferences/Plugins/File Browser/Configure and set the default path for the music library (that may well be an external drive).

After that, you will see the music folders in DeaDBeeF in a left panel and each folder can be added (queued) to an existing or new playlist.

[image]